# Cauchy problem with real parameter?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I guys. I'm doing this problem:
$$\begin{cases}
y'(x)=\frac{2y(x)}{x}+3x^{\alpha} \\ 
y(1)=2\\
\end{cases}
$$
with $\alpha\in \mathbb R^{+}$ constant.

I have started studying the existence and uniqueness of solutions.
So
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2y(x)}{x}+3x^{\alpha}$$
Has domain $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^{2} :x\neq0\}$.

I notice that $f(x,y$) is a continuous function on it's domain, so it's a derivable function and for this reason I can say that is locally Lipschitz continuous. So I can apply the local exinstance and uniqueness theorem.

Moreover $f(x,y)$ it's not Lipschitz in $y$ respect to $x$ on $D$, so it's not globally Lipschitz continuous and I can't apply the global existance and uniquess theorem for the solutions.

Now I want to find explicitly the solutions, depending on $\alpha$, and finally I want to find the value of $\alpha$ for which

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}y(x)=+\infty$$

Assuming all is correct from the beginning to this point, the equation could be solved by separation of variables:

$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3x^{\alpha}}{y(x)}$$

Is this the most convenient possibility to solve this equation? Because I'm a little bit stucked at this point. Any suggestions to get the goal? Thanl you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cauchy problem has a unique global solution in $(0,+\infty)$ because the [differential equation is linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation).

Moreover, after multiplying by the [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) $1/x^2$ we have:
$$\left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)'=\frac{y'(x)}{x^2}-\frac{2y(x)}{x^3}=3x^{\alpha-2}.$$
Then after integrating both side we obtain:

i) if $\alpha\not=1$, 
$$\frac{y(x)}{x^2}=\int 3x^{\alpha-2}\,dx=\frac{3x^{\alpha-1}}{\alpha-1}+C\implies y(x)=\frac{3x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha-1}+Cx^2;$$

ii) if $\alpha=1$,
$$\frac{y(x)}{x^2}=\int 3x^{-1}\,dx=3\ln(x)+C \implies y(x)=3x^2\ln(x)+Cx^2.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am thinking about the domain.

 For sure I have $\alpha>0$. But why $x$ couldn't be negative?

 If i pick (just for an example)  $x=-1$ and $\alpha=2$ I would have $$3(-1)^{2}=9$$
That is a real positive number. What do you think about it? Am I strongly in error? Thank you.



Edit: Maybe it gives some trouble when $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$ because we're going into $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Usually the domain of the solution of a Cauchy problem is an interval (a connected set) which contain the initial point ($1$ in this case). Moreover if $\alpha$ is irrational  $x^{\alpha}$ is not defined for $x<0$ (what is $(-2)^{\pi}$?)

Comment: Yes, It's definitely the point of my edit. We don't want to work with compex numbers.

Comment: And what about existance and uniqueness of solutions? I just don't care about theorems, I just see that it's linear so for sure I have a unique global solution. Is it ok now? Thank you.

Comment: Yes! Moreover here we also found explicit solutions which are defined for $x>0$.

Comment: Tell me. What is it?

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I have only one doubt left. I have:

$$\frac{y'(x)}{x^{2}}-\frac{2y(x)}{x^{3}}=3x^{\alpha-2}$$.

I have the solution $y(x)$ without the intermediate steps. I've tried with separation of variables with no results. Do you have a hint for me? Thank you.

Comment: No separation of variables. Notice that the left-hand side is the derivative of $y/x^2$. Then integrate both sides.

Comment: Ok, I've see what you mean.

$$\left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)'=\frac{y'(x)}{x^2}-\frac{2y(x)}{x^3}$$

Now integrating both sides it's easy, and I finally get $y(x)$. I also have to pay attention about different cases for $\alpha$. Thank you for you patient, your help it's very useful for me to learn. Could I ask if you know a source for some exercies to do to improve my skills on this topics? Thank you.

Comment: For example, take a look here: http://www.tau.ac.il/~levant/ode/lesson_3.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll post new questions if I'll have problems. Your help is precious :).

Comment: I have tried to re-do this exercise but another doubt has raised up on me.
I have $$\frac{y'}{x^2}=\frac{2y}{x^{2}}+3x^{\alpha}$$
I have divided all the terms by $1/x^{2}$.
But if i try to integrate my result is:
$$\int\frac{y'}{x^2}dy=\int\frac{2y}{x^{2}}dy+\int3x^{\alpha}dx$$
Is this wrong? Thank you :). 
Ps.: Sono anche io italiano, e ho visto alcune sue lezioni su Youtube! @Robert-z

Comment: @muserock92 If you divide  $y'(x)=\frac{2y(x)}{x}+3x^{\alpha}$ by $x^2$ and integrate with respect to $x$ then you should have 
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{x^2}dx=\int\frac{2y(x)}{x^{3}}dx+\int3x^{\alpha-2}dx$$. 
P:S. I am glad that you appreciate my videos ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much!
I really think that your video are very useful and you are a great teacher! Ne approfitto per chiederle un consiglio: mi servirebbero esercizi su sequenze di funzioni in spazi $L^{1}$ e convergenza puntuale ma non riesco proprio a trovare niente. Ho paura che non facendo esercizi la sola teoria non mi basterà ad affrontare le varie situazioni che mi si potrebbero presentare. Ha qualche consiglio da darmi? La ringrazio davvero molto e ancora complimenti.

Comment: @muserock92 Please, send me an email. I will try to give you some references.